# ExtJS Quicktip constrains problem

Tags: tooltip, extjs

I've got a column renderer defined that creates a HTML fragment which contains the ext.qtip attributes to create a quicktip. All works fine, the image renders in the grid cell, when i hover over the image a tooltip with the larger image is shown ... all nice but the quicktip on the bottom row expands beyond the constraints of the panel, is there any way to make it stay inside the panel boundaries?

```
var thumbRenderer = function(value, meta, record){
    var thumbPath   = Config.baseUrl + 'images/thumb/' + record.get('filename');
    var previewPath = Config.baseUrl + 'images/big/' + record.get('filename');
    return String.format('<img src="{0}" ext:qwidth="312" ext:qtip="<img style=\'margin: 2px 0;width:300px;\' src=\'{1}\' />" width="60" class="pic" />', thumbPath, previewPath);
}
```

[image: tooltip]

Comment: Have u finish that? plz update your solution

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the showAt method:

```
tip.showAt([x,y]);
```

Where x and y are the respective x and y co-ordinate positions.

EDIT: You can also use the `showBy()` method on a QuickTip instance:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Tip.html#method-Ext.Tip-showBy

Comment: I'm thinking more in the [alignTo()](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Element.alignment.html#method-Ext.Element-alignTo) method which accepts a coordinate system like 'tl-bl?' which means that the element should align it's top left edge to the bottom left edge of the target and constrain to the viewport (the questionmark parameter). I don't seem to find any way to translate this to the quicktips class.